# Shimano GRX Hydraulic Disc Sub Brake Levers with 105 groupset

Tags: shimano, brakes, compatibility, grx

The GRX groupsets seem to be compatible with common road groupsets (Tiagra, 105, Ultegra) which was also pointed out in [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74333/63564). Furthermore, a [brief news article by Shimano](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/information/news/gravel-upgrades--mixing-and-matching-shimano-grx-and-road-compon.html) states that the brake and drivetrain components between GRX and road groupsets are interchangeable/interoperable:

> Fully Compatible Parts
>
> As long as you maintain your current drivetrain
> speeds (10-speed versus 11-speed), the following GRX components are
> fully compatible and interchangeable with your existing parts: Shift
> levers, chains, brake calipers, bottom brackets, cables and housing,
> and Di2 batteries and accessories.

However, some additional [brake levers *BL-RX812*](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/BL-RX812-R.html) for the upright position were introduced with the GRX series about which I cannot find any explicit compatibility
information.

As Shimano's STIs combine brake and shift levers, I am not sure whether

> Shift levers

refers to STIs (including the brake levers which I am concerned about).

Are the brake hoses of 105 STIs compatible with the GRX ones? Could I extend the road groupset brakes (105 or Ultegra) with these sub brake levers resulting in a setup consisting of 105 drivetrain, 105 STIs and GRX sub brake levers?

Comment: My guess is yes, as I believe all high-end Shimano stuff uses BH90.

Answer (score 2):

Shimano has a great compatibility website.

[This](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/?q=BL-RX812&enter=1&cid=C-453&acid=C-499) is what I have found. They seem to be compatible with pretty much any hydraulic STI from Shimano and the 105 STIs (ST-R7020) are listed as compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In looking thru Shimano's latest compatibility chart (specifically the section of "Compatibility of Shimano hydraulic disc brake hose") I too do not see specific reference to the BL-RX812 and the BH90 hose. However, looking thru the [RX812's Dealer Manual](https://si.shimano.com/#/en/DM/GADBR01), it clearly states that the BH90 hose is to be used with the levers and calipers dealt with in the dealer manual.  Specifically, SM-BH90-JK-SSR (see pg.7 of the dealer's manual).  It also sounds like the BL-RX812 sub brake lever will come with the appropriate hose to continue on from the sub lever to the STI.